# Is this function periodic?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Is the following function periodic?

> $$f(x)=\cos(x)*\cos(x\sqrt5)$$

A function $f$ is said to be periodic with period $P$ ($P$ being a nonzero constant) if we have
$$f(x+P) = f(x)$$ 
for all values of $x$. If there exists a least positive constant $P$ with this property, it is called the prime period. A function with period $P$ will repeat on intervals of length $P$, and these intervals are referred to as periods.

Comment: What have I tried? I don't know what to do with it, that's why I am here, to find help. I want to know: does this function have a period? That's all.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @SerikLavrinyk : what people are trying to say is that they want to see you try something, anything, so when you see the answer you understand it, and maybe make a different answer of your own. you already have all the knowledge needed to solve this on your own.

Comment: @Arjang: I am very very well, in SRAKU do you do!

Comment: Do not vandalize the questions you've asked after you receive a response. It is rude and inconsiderate to the users who have worked to answer your question; I am flagging these *repeated* actions for the moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$2 \cdot \cos(\alpha) \cdot \cos(\beta)= \cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)$$

Hence
$$ \cos(x)\cdot \cos(\sqrt{5} x) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos( (1+\sqrt{5}) x)+\cos((1-\sqrt{5}) x))$$

So in fact we are interessted if there is an $x$ such that
\begin{align*}
(1+\sqrt{5})x&= m \cdot 2 \pi\\
(1-\sqrt{5})x&= n\cdot 2\pi
\end{align*}
where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. As $x=0$ solves it, we only need to find another solution.

So we can say $x \neq 0$. We devide the equations as both sides are surely not equal to zero.
$$ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}} = \frac{m}{n}$$
Now we simplify the left hand set

\begin{align*}
\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}}
 &=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1-\sqrt{5}}\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{1+\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^2}{1-5}\\
&=-\frac{1+2\sqrt{5}+5}{4}\\
&=-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}

So we have

$$-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{m}{n}$$
Now this is equal to 
$$-\sqrt{5}= 2\cdot \frac{m}{n}+3 $$
where the right hand side is surely in the rationals, as $m,n$ are integers and $3$ is an integer.
The left hand side is not in the rationals.

Comment: Thank you very much! You just have saved one life!

Comment: @SerikLavrinyk I did make it a bit more explicit

Comment: We are very grateful to you)